# xxhdpi text to textView textSize

Tags: android, textview, text-size

I have a design guide of 1080 * 1920.

There are several texts on the guide which should be shown as textViews.

On this case, how should I define the textSize of each texts?

If a text's height is 40px, it would be 13.3dp in xxhdpi.

But, when I make the textSize as 13.3dp, it looks rather smaller. 
When trying to show numbers or english characters, it becomes even smaller.

What tactics should I need to make the view as similar as the design guide?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're using dp instead of sp for text size?

Comment: you should use sp instead of dp

Comment: It's because I do not want the app's text size to change.

Comment: And, as far as I know, if the android device's text setting is on default, sp or dp doesn't have any differences, isn't it?

Comment: `If a text's height is 40px, it would be 13.3dp in xxhdpi.` Based on what?

Comment: @Kling Klang Well, as to a image, if it's height is 40px, it will be 13.3dp in xxhdpi. But, this calculation doesn't seem to work on texts.

Comment: `if it's height is 40px, it will be 13.3dp in xxhdpi` Based on what?